# Why does Visual C++ fail to compile a friend template inheriting from a private nested class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

Consider the following code:

```
class A {
  class B {};

  template <typename T>
  friend class C;
};

template <typename T>
class C : A::B {};

int main() { C<int> c; }
```

It compiles fine with GCC and Clang but Visual C++ 2010 gives an error:

```
test.cc(11) : error C2248: 'A::B' : cannot access private class declared in class 'A'
```

Is it a bug in Visual C++ or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the 1998 standard and the 2011 standard contain essentially the same code as an example, in 14.5.3 #4 and  14.5.4 #3, respectively.

```
class X {
  template<class T> friend struct A;
  class Y { };
};
template<class T> struct A { X::Y ab; }; // OK
template<class T> struct A<T*> { X::Y ab; }; // OK
```

Apparently it's a bug.

Comment: Interestingly enough, Comeau's (online) C++ compiler also doesn't like the OP's example code. It's starting to get pretty outdated though.

Comment: The thing is, MSVC 2010 compiles your example fine (including instantiating an `A<int> a1;` and `A<int*> a2;`), but it doesn't compile the OP's example. So there's some difference between the two that MSVC doesn't like, and there might be some legitimate detail why.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, interesting enough, the VS2010/VS2012/VS Nov 2012 CTP give an error on the OP code, but succeed on `template <typename T>
class C : A::B { A::B x; };` :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is most certainly a bug in the Visual C++ compiler.

<sup>Footnote: the GCC compiler compiles it fine.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `A::B` is private to `A`.

This could mean, but that's my interpretation, and I would have to back it up with a paragraph from the standard, that you cannot reference `A::B` in the global scope, let alone declare anything a subclass of `A::B`, nor can you create a pointer to `A::B` etc...

On the other hand, `X` *has* access to `A::B`, so *it* can declare a subclass of it:

```
class A {
  class B {
  };
  template<typename T> friend class X;
  template<typename T> friend class Y;
};

template<typename T> class X : public A::B{};

template<typename T>
class Y {
  class B2 : public A::B {};
};

int main() { 
   X<int> x; 
   Y<int> y;
}
```

For this snippet, Comeau does not tell me that `Y` cannot be instantiated.  Nor does VS2005.

Comment: Then why does `template <typename T> class C : A::B { A::B x; };` work as pointed out by @chill?

Comment: @vitaut: does he mention vs2005?

Comment: Nope. I am actually interested in vc2010 but do you mean that vc2005 doesn't accept this too? So it's either another bug introduced in vc2010 which less likely or a half-cooked fix for the original bug.